# Javascript array is not completely assigned to php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, get

Below is my array contents in javascript. I'm passing it using get call to a php page. I am also passing other array's along with this array. Those array values are passed completely. Only this array is passing partial values. I also alerted it in javascript and its complete there. Whereas in php its taking only 2 values instead of 14.

```
var testPlanNameArray= ["Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Cascading Validation", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility alias for defth", "Eligibility-Submitter x", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partner alias", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partne", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partner", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting ", "Custom Maps Validation", "Custom Maps Validation", "Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Custom Maps Validation", "Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Custom Maps Validation"];
```

I'm passing using below code to php

```
$.get("dbValidation.php?&testIDArray=" + testIDArray + "&testPlanNameArray=" + testPlanNameArray + "&errorArray=" + errorArray + "&historyErrorDescArray=" + historyErrorDescArray  + "&expectedDEPProp=" + expectedDEPProp  + "&actualDEPProp=" + actualDEPProp).done(function(data3) {
                                // alert(testPlanNameArray);
                                        console.log(data3);
                                        console.log(testPlanNameArray);
                            });
```

In php page Iam just doing

```
<?php
$testPlanNameArray = explode(",", $_GET['testPlanNameArray']);
print_r($testPlanNameArray);
?>
```

When I do console.log(data3) it will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Cascading Validation
    [1] => Eligibility-SubmitterRouting 
)
```

I tried  $testPlanNameArray = json_decode($_GET['testPlanNameArray']); but still it is not taking complete value. The problem is only with respect to this array. For rest array it is working fine.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` show?

Comment: It is printing ["Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Cascading Validation", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility alias for defth", "Eligibility-Submitter x", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partner alias", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partne", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting & Partner", "Eligibility-SubmitterRouting ", "Custom Maps Validation", "Custom Maps Validation", "Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Custom Maps Validation", "Eligibility-Real Time Eligibility Custom Maps Validation"]   in console.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It should print an associative array with all the parameter names as keys.

Comment: Like `"testPlanNameArray" => Array(15) ( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an encoding issue. I suggest you pass an object to `$.get`, and it will encode it properly.

```
$.get("dbValidation.php", {
    testIDArray: testIDArray,
    testPlanNameArray: testPlanNameArray,
    errorArray: errorArray,
    historyErrorDescArray: historyErrorDescArray,
    expectedDEPProp: expectedDEPProp,
    actualDEPProp: actualDEPProp
}).done(...)
```

This encoding will actually create arrays in the `$_GET` parameters, so you don't need to use `explode()` or `json_decode()` at all.

Note that there's generally a limit to the length of URL parameters, typically 1024 or 2048. So trying to pass long arrays on the URL may not work well. You should use `$.post`, which has much higher limits.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Barmar . I will try now and let you know in short time.

Comment: I tried above answer and in php I did $testIDArray = $_GET['testIDArray'];
$testPlanNameArray = $_GET['testPlanNameArray'];
// $testPlanNameArray = json_decode($_GET['testPlanNameArray']);
// $testPlanNameArray = array(explode(",", $_GET['testPlanNameArray']));
$errorArray = $_GET['errorArray'];
$historyErrorDescArray = $_GET['historyErrorDescArray'];
// $errorArraySecond = explode(",", $_GET['errorArraySecond']);
$expectedDEPProp = $_GET['expectedDEPProp'];
$actualDEPProp = $_GET['actualDEPProp'];

Comment: I'm getting 414 status in browser console

Comment: That's the error for a URL too long. You're running into the limit I mentioned.

Comment: You need to switch to POST.

Comment: How to send parameters using post. Should I replace get with post both in javascript and php ?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need to do. You can also use `$_REQUEST` in PHP. That contains the merge of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, so the PHP will work with either style.

Comment: Avoid accessing $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER, $_COOKIES directly. Use `filter_input`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson FYI I've never used that function in my entire career. However, when using parameters in queries, you should use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Not running `filter_input` or some other filtration mechanism is a great way to open your website to XSS or other vulnerabilities. Naturally protecting your database is a separate issue, but I would recommend looking into it. It's more convenient in many ways even if it feels a bit more verbose at first. Note: this is not a substitution for prepared SQL statements. It's just good practice.